# Is it necessary to define <head> and <body> with "loadHTMLString" in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

Is it necessary to define `<head>` and `<body>` with "loadHTMLString" in UIWebView?

When using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` in UIWebView, Those two HTML comes same result.

1.

```
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\"> </head> <body> <div class=label1-con3> <font color=#ff0000 size=3> <strong>Test</strong></font> </div> </body> </html>
```

2.

```
<div class=label1-con3> <font color=#ff0000 size=3> <strong>Test</strong></font> </div>
```

Comment: no it's not necessary.

Comment: @Chris No its not necessary . you add directly your htmlstring .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not necessary at all, it's just user's requirement that how they wanna show their web template. So it's not necessary for all to use this kind of stuff it's just requirement that changes per senario.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not necessary to add these tags.
You can add string of your own and it will work fine